# Single call-to-action for 'Sign Up' and 'Log In'?

Tags: mobile, navigation

For the narrow view of a layout we're trying to consolidate the 'Sign Up' and 'Log In' buttons in the header to make the calls to action and click targets larger.

Any thoughts on a word or phrase that can communicate both of these ideas?

Using one or the other alone would seem to be confusing to those it doesn't normally apply to (e.g. using just 'Log In' might leave me wondering what to do if I don't already have an account.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term **Sign In** can be used for both actions. It's also a good term if you're providing additional Sign In options like Facebook, Twitter or OpenId, as "Sign in using Facebook" doesn't imply the burden of a (possibly lenghty) registration process.

Comment: Interesting. That variation slipped completely past me - pains of being too close I suppose ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if;

**'My Account'**

Could work here. Users with an account will easily identify where to log in and it also could communicate account creation to those who don't have one.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where business requested to show a button with Login and register with one action. I do understand that its not best practice and user may get confuse here with  double action with one button. Also, we have provide a separate link for register.

See below screen which may help you in your scenario to create My profile link for Login.
[image]

Comment: I literally just joined this site, but I'm pretty sure that's awful practice from a security standpoint, as it allows easy testing of accounts. Note that most popular websites force you to give both a username and a password, and will then say the *combination* wasn't right, to avoid giving away whether or not the account exists.

Comment: @raptortech97 it IS a security issue. Also, the additional steps do not seem good from a UX perspective, my profile --> login/ enter username --> enter password. That's an extra screen / form each time an existing user return.

Comment: @raptortech97 Actually, it's not, since any website that requires unique usernames allow you to check if a username is available when you are signing up.

Comment: @you786 Except that many (most?) signup systems have much stronger rate limiting and often captcha systems